# Spring Cloud Consul - test connection

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, service-discovery

I am working on learning [Spring Cloud Consul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/) and want to write a little utility that spits back data from the Consul instance that I am connected to.  I can easily autowire and work with the [DiscoveryClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/discovery/ConsulDiscoveryClient.java), but I do not get back any data that makes it appear as though I am not connected to the service (running in my Docker container in development mode).

In order to troubleshoot, I want to write a little endpoint or service that rips through the information about the service and reports any errors on the connection (nothing is showing up in my application logs).

I want to troubleshoot the configuration on my own, which is why I am looking for some inspection information.  Below are the configuration options I have set up if you are interested in helping further, but I am really looking for some internal, deep inspection data I can spit to my logs since I do not get any right now.

In my Maven `pom.xml` I have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In `bootstrap.yml` I have:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: HelloWorld
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        healthCheckInterval: 15s
        tags: name=TestApplication, module=HelloWorld
```

Comment: You need `spring.application.name`

Comment: I got the problem fixed (I needed to launch Consul with `-client 0.0.0.0`), but I still want to inspect the information.

Comment: @spencergibb I have that in there - I was just making the assumption it was understood.  I updated the post to include it explicitly.

Comment: Can you share a project that recreates the problem?

Comment: @spencergibb if I get a chance I will Github the whole thing.  I will see what I can do after work today.